# I've made an app in Unity and want it to be part of Facebook with ads down the side like Farmville. How do I do this?

Tags: facebook, canvas, unity-game-engine

I've made an app in Unity and want it to be part of Facebook with ads down the side like Farmville. How do I do this? I used the Unity Web Player HTML page and all that happens when I click 'Go to App' is it just sends me to this page. Help?

Answer (score 0):

The Unity part of your game is just the client-side part of the application; you also need to develop a server-side part of the application. The server side part of the application doesn't have to be complicated; I would recommend some PHP or something to integrate with Facebook's services, but at a minimum you just have to host the page on your own web server and tell Facebook to point to that. Facebook doesn't actually host your webpage, you simply tell Facebook where to link to.

As for the ads, some ads are automatic and part of Facebook. Any additional ads you want to run come from a 3rd-party ad network like RockYou.